# PHP $_POST getting undefined index, even though inputs are given

Tags: php, post

I am trying to get a username and password from an HTML form using $_POST method,
but i am getting an undefined index error with given input.

the form portion of my index file is as follows

```
<form class="form-signin"  role="form"action="" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">title<em class='current'>title</em></h2>
        <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input name ="submit" type="submit" value="sign in">
      </form>
```

i also have my php script (called auth.php) included in the top of my index file.

this is my auth.php script code sample

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "auth is called";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "submit is pressed";
//this if statement enters when submit is pressed
if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
echo "Username or Password is empty";
//this if statement enters too, even with input given
}
else{
echo "YAY";
}
}
?>
```

The "username or password is empty" statement keeps getting printed, even when I enter in a username and password into the input fields. What is the problem

Comment: I didn't have input name defined in the form, not sure how I missed that. Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Missing "name" `attribute in input` fields, it should be

*EDIT 2 :* Missing **type="text"** in username `input`

```
 <input type="text" name='username' id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
 <input name='password' id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Comment: Also, there is no input type `username`. It should be `text`.

Comment: @CodingAnt you have 2 types attr. in the first input!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `username` input's type to `"text"`:

```
<input name='username' id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<input name='password' id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your form , 1. Name missing, 2. No datatype with the name of username

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="" name="loginform" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">title<em class='current'>title</em></h2>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="sign in">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

input **`type = text`** and **`name attr`** required

```
 <input name='username' id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
```

Check values using `print_r()` or `var_dump` if you are not getting the desired output.

This will help you to check which part of your code malfunctions. If you have done so, you would have found that there's something wrong only in your html form content, as you wont be having any field content printed and you would have easily sorted it out...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "auth is called";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "submit is pressed";
    //this if statement enters when submit is pressed
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    echo "Username or Password is empty";
    //this if statement enters too, even with input given
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['username']){
      echo "Username  is empty";
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['password']){
      echo "Password  is empty";
    }
    else{
    echo "YAY";
    }
    }
    ?>
```